# Using awk in Python to insert text in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, awk, insert

I am having some trouble inserting some text using Python. I have a file, `Package.swift` with the following:

```
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "LibCore",
      path: "lib/core/"
    ),
    .target(
      name: "LibAppData",
      dependencies: ["LibCore"],
      path: "lib/appdata/",
      swiftSettings: [.define("appdata")]
    ),
```

I want to insert a new `.target()` right below the opening `targets: [`

This works using `awk` in zsh:

```
    awk '{print} /\.target\(/ && !n {print "      name: \"{full_name}\",\n      dependencies: \[\"LibCore\"\],\n      path: \"lib\/{short_name}\/\",\n      swiftSettings: [.define(\"{short_name}\")]\n    ),\n    .target("; n++}' Package.swift > Package-new.swift && mv Package-new.swift Package.swift
```

I have tried the following in Python:

1. ```
   subprocess.call([f"awk '{print} /\\.target\\(/ && !n {{print "      name: "{full_name}\",\n      dependencies: \\[\"LibCore\"\\],\n      path: \"lib\\/{short_name}\\/\",\n      swiftSettings: [.define(\"{short_name}\")]\n    ),\n    .target("; n++ "}}' Package.swift > Package-new.swift && mv Package-new.swift Package.swift"], shell=True)
   ```
2. ```
   subprocess.call(['awk.exe', '{print} /\\.target\\(/ && !n {print "      name: \"{full_name}\",\n      dependencies: \\[\"LibCore\"\\],\n      path: \"lib\\/{short_name}\\/\",\n      swiftSettings: [.define(\"{short_name}\")]\n    ),\n    .target("; n++}', 'Package.swift'])
   ```
3. ```
       tmp=tempfile.mkstemp()
       with open("Package.swift") as fd1, open(tmp[1],'w') as fd2:
           for line in fd1:
               line = line.replace("\\.target\\(",f"      name: \"{full_name}\",\n      dependencies: \\[\"LibCore\"\\],\n      path: \"lib\\/{short_name}\\/\",\n      swiftSettings: [.define(\"{short_name}\")]\n    ),\n    .target(")
               fd2.write(line)
       os.rename(tmp[1],"Package.swift")
   ```
4. ```
       newtext = '''\
               name: "{full_name}\",\n      dependencies: \\[\"LibCore\"\\],\n      path: \"lib\\/{short_name}\\/\",\n      swiftSettings: [.define(\"{short_name}\")]\n    ),\n    .target(
               '''
       filename = 'Package.swift'
       for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
           if re.match(r'\\.target\\(', line):
               sys.stdout.write(newtext.format(l=line))
           else:
               sys.stdout.write(line)
   ```

I have also tried many variations of these trying to escape the {}, but still every time I get a  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I try and run the script. In case it isn't obvious, Python is not my first language

Would anyone know what I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using f-strings, make sure you're using a version of Python that supports f-strings. That's 3.6 or higher.

Comment: Thanks @Aesin! I have some other commands using f strings in the script that are working, so I think am good to go

Comment: Do you *need* to use `awk`, or are other solutions welcome?

Comment: Other solutions are welcome for sure, as long as I can include in the script :)

Comment: @christinam And even thought this is a Swift package manifest, you have to do this in Python?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer it. This is part of a release builder script and this is the last piece!

Answer (score 0):

The Problems:

1. In 1, you've missed several double-quote characters `"` that need to be escaped.
2. This line seems syntactically fine in *Python*, but running awk from within Python is always going to be a bit gross. However, it's a syntax error in *awk*. Unlike some other languages, single-quoted strings in Python still treat escape characters as escape characters, so, for example, `'"'` and `'\"'` are the same string literal.

   That means that this example: `"name: \"{full_name}\""` gets converted to `"name: "{full_name}""` which messes up your quoting when fed to awk.
3. With this one you've gone too far the other way: too much escaping.

   This: `line = line.replace("\\.target\\(",` never matches, because your file doesn't contain the string: `\.target\(`.

   It's not a syntax error, though, it just won't do anything.
4. As they say, now you have two problems. Or, actually, three problems. Your regex has the same problem as in (3), `match()` is the wrong call to use here, and the `string.format` doesn't work like that.

   The mis-escaped regex should give you this error when the re package tries to use it:

   `re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position XX` (where XX is a line number)

   If you remove the excess escaping from the regex, you get this: `\.target\(`. If the `Package.swift` file had no indentation, you'd be fine with this, but it does have indentation, and the `re.match` function only gets a match if the pattern matches from the **beginning** of the string. You want `re.search`, to match anywhere. Alternatively, you could change your pattern to match any number of whitespace characters before the `.target` string, like this: `[ \t]*\.target\(`.

   So, last problem: f-strings pull in variables from the scope they're in, but `string.format` doesn't: each value needs to be passed in as the value of a dictionary, and the `l=line` you've specified here... doesn't do anything? On top of that, because you replace the `.target(` string instead of altering it or rewriting it, your output file isn't syntactically valid Swift.

In a few cases here, I feel like you've missed important parts of the documentation for the library calls you've made? In case you're working off something else, [the official Python documentation is good, and pretty helpful!](https://docs.python.org/3.8/index.html)

In addition, the error messages you *should* see from each of these snippets are totally different (in one case, no error at all). If you change this much and the error messages you see *aren't* totally different, then the problem isn't in this part of the code.

Comment: Thanks @Aesin, I have tried all the corrections you have mentioned but still not successful. Mind posting a code snippet of what you think it _should_ be?